# redsocks Basic Authentication fails with HTTP-proxy

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, iptables, http-proxy

I'm using 
 - redoscks/0.5 (libevnt-2..8) 
 - on a 2018-4 4.18.0kliad64.

I need to connect to an http-proxy that require authentication and I want to use redsocks to redirect to that proxy (by means of iptables) some hhtp/https traffic.
I set redsocks.conf in this way

```
base {
     log_debug = on;
     log_info = on;
     log = "stderr";
     daemon = off;
     redirector = iptables;
}
redsocks {
      local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
      local_port = 12345;
      ip = 10.12.yyy.xxx;
      port = 8080;
      // known types: socks4, socks5, http-connect, http-relay
      type = http-connect;
      login = "myUser";
      password = "myPass";
      disclose_src = false;
}
```

But it seems that redsocks does NOT consider my credential.

I sniff traffic with wireshark and compare it with a proxychains connection that works fine (with same IP,Port,user and pass parameter).

1. wireshark session with redsocks:

   [from redsocks to proxy]
   *CONNECT 216.58.205.100:80 HTTP/1.0*

   [from proxy to redsocks]
   HTTP/1.0 407 authenticationrequired
   Via: 1.0 10.12.yyy.xxx (McAfee Web Gateway 7.7.2.7.0.24770)
   Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2019 09:25:22 GMT
   Content-Type: text/html
   Cache-Control: no-cache
   Content-Length: 4040
   Proxy-Connection: Close
   Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
   Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="McAfee Web Gateway"
   ....
2. wireshark session with proxychains:

   [from redsocks to proxy]
   ***** CONNECT 185.63.145.1:443 HTTP/1.0
   Proxy-Authorization: Basic ZjI1MjE5Y...*****

   [from proxy to redsocks]
   HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
   ...

So it seems that proxychains (which work fine) send a CONNECT command together with a Proxy-Authorization, but redsocks no and because of that proxy close the connection.

What's wrong on my config setup ?
  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?
We have 2 separate redsocks container running (all equal), one works, but not the other one.